# Object value resetting back to _init_() value immediately after updating

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to make a pong multiplayer game. The game works but the score update won't.

I created and ran the `Ball` class in server file and called the `score()` function there to update and pass to the client. It works and adds 1 point if these conditions are met but in the next iteration the score is set back to 0.

Score-checking function from the `Ball` class (`p` is a player object):

```py
def score(self, p):
    if self.x <= 10:  
        print('true')
        p.score += 1
    elif self.x >= 890:
        print('true')
        p.score += 1
```

`Player` class:

```py
class Player:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.rect = (x, y, width, height)
        self.vel = 7
        self.score = 0
```

Server file where the function is called:

```py
while True:
    if current_player > 0:
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        clock.tick(60)
        print(players[current_player].score)
        ball.score(players[current_player])
        print(players[current_player].score)
        ball_data = ball.move(players[0], players[1]
```

`ball_data()` is used to store the `Ball` object to pass to the client. The `print()` calls were used for debugging purposes.

```
players = [
    Player(10, 300 - PLAYER_HEIGHT/2, PLAYER_WIDTH, PLAYER_HEIGHT, WHITE), 
    Player(880, 300 - PLAYER_HEIGHT/2, PLAYER_WIDTH, PLAYER_HEIGHT, WHITE)
    ]

ball = Ball(WIDTH, HEIGHT, 10, WHITE)

def handle_client(conn, current_player):
    print(f'[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected')
    conn.send(pickle.dumps([players[current_player], ball])) # 0 is player and 1 is ball
    reply = ''
    ball_data = ball

    while True:
        if current_player > 0:
            clock = pygame.time.Clock()
            clock.tick(60)
            print(players[current_player].score)
            ball.score(players[current_player])
            print(players[current_player].score)
            ball_data = ball.move(players[0], players[1])

        try:
            data = pickle.loads(conn.recv(2048))
            players[current_player] = data

            if not data:
                print('DISCONNETED')
                break
            else:
                if current_player == 0:
                    reply = [players[1], ball_data]
                else:
                    reply = [players[0], ball_data]

            conn.sendall(pickle.dumps(reply))
        except:
            remove_player()
            player_reset()
            ball_reset()
            break
        
    print('Lost connection')
    conn.close()
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Can you add your class statements?

Comment: Added. I added almost whole of the server file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may happen on the list of players. If the score is reset to 0, means the player list may have been reset (reinitialized).

```py
data = pickle.loads(conn.recv(2048))
print("tracking:", data)
players[current_player] = data
```

Comment: But if the list is reset shouldn't all the values of player reset like it x and y pos. It does not change and stays the same. only the score resets. Also the list initialization is outside the loop.

Comment: the players data will be updated in "players[current_player] = data", you can track the data changes to debug.

Comment: I partly fixed the issue by calling the score function in the. But now the score updates by 3 points instead of 1.